# Docker pruning, how remove newer images and keep older ones (opposite of 'until' filter)

Tags: docker

Is there a way to have docker remove all images and containers newer than, say, 48 hours?

All the examples I see using filter use `until=xxxxx` which assumes the oldest ones are to be discarded, but in our case we want to *keep* our older ones and discard any exploratory images/containers created for one-off purposes in the past 48 hours.

Comment: Can you put a mark on the name?